# jQuery .post() content reverts back to original content with subsequent jQuery calls

Tags: jquery, dom, client-server

I've replaced content with .post() using a form and db call. The new content is another form and data table from a php query. I then use the new form on the new table to change some css. However, when I enter data in the new form, on the click event, the content reverts back to the original content. I know I'm not changing the server side of the page content, but I thought jQuery works on the current DOM.

Original Content:

```
<div id="bodyContent">
 <form id="usualValidate" class="mainForm" method="post" action="">
 <label>Barcode:<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="required" name="startBarcode" id="startBarcode"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="blueBtn" id="startBtn" />
 </form>
</div>
```

Replaced Content:

```
<div id="bodyContent">    
 <form id="checkinProcess" class="mainForm" method="post" action="">
  <label>Barcode:<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="required" name="processBarocdes" id="processBarcodes"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="blueBtn" id="submitBtn" />
</form>
<table id="shippedBarcodesTable">
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody id="shippedBarcodes">
    <tr id="B000503513">...</tr>
    <tr id="B000496123">...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JS: The first loads the new content. The second highlights a row in the table that is loaded. Highlight script works in a traditional page set-up with whole page refresh. But trying to load a dynamic table with jQuery, then highlight a row in the table with subsequent jQuery, causes it to revert back to original source content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#startBtn").on("click", startCheckin);
function startCheckin(sevt) {
  sevt.preventDefault();
  var startBC = $("#startBarcode").val();
  $.post("checkin_process.php",
    {startBarcode : startBC},
     function(data) {
       $("#bodyContent").html(data);
     });
}

$("#submitBtn").on("click", highlight); 
function highlight(hevt) {
  hevt.preventDefault();
  var scanbc = $("#processBarcodes").val();
  $("#" + scanbc).addClass("curChecked");
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + scanbc).offset().top-150}, 750);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `highlight` function is never called, because it's not connected with the dynamically created button. Because of that default action of submit button is called - the form is submitted and the page is refreshing because there is no action URL defined. And that's why you see the page as it was before the `$.post` call.

To fix this you should change this line

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click", highlight);
```

to something like that:

```
$("body").on("click", "#submitBtn", highlight);
```

You should connect your function with element that is not loaded dynamically with selector of item(s) that you want to fire this event as second parameter in `on` function. Check [`.on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info.

And BTW, definitions of your functions don't have to be inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Thank you. I see what your saying. Reading the .on documentation, I understand it better now that I see it in my own code.

Comment: @RoloTomassi I'm glad I could help. Reading documentation is the best first step on the way of understanding why something is not working as you expected. ^^